# Java : How to remove quotes from Json keys using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to strip the double quotes from a complex Json structure (object with children object and arrays in the hierarchy). I'm writing in Java (the app will run on Android).

I already have the string produced from a Json lib (Gson)  and I am trying to strip the double quotes using regex instead of deserializing it back to an object and then serializing it without the double quotes in the key names.

I cannot find the right pattern or patterns to replace them.

example Json:

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"555f9ecd-2ced-42b7-b956-33e759bf8db1",
"key3":false,
"key4_parent":{
"child_key5":"Android",
"id":"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
"name":"danny",
"bypassed":false
},
"object1":{
"deviceType":"Android",
"id":"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
"base64val":"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
"name":"john"
},
"requiredLevel":"PUSH",
"level":"debug",
"status":1012,
"description":"Authentication in progress",
"objects":[
{
"deviceType":"Android",
"id":"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
"base64val":"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
"name":"john"
},
{
"deviceType":"Android",
"id":"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
"base64val":"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
"name":"john"
}
]
}
```

expected output :

```
{
key1:"value1",
key2:"555f9ecd-2ced-42b7-b956-33e759bf8db1",
key3:false,
key4_parent:{
child_key5:"Android",
id:"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
name:"danny",
bypassed:false
},
object1:{
deviceType:"Android",
id:"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
base64val:"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
name:"john"
},
requiredLevel:"PUSH",
level:"debug",
status:1012,
description:"Authentication in progress",
objects:[
{
deviceType:"Android",
id:"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
base64val:"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
name:"john"
},
{
deviceType:"Android",
id:"7ae2facc-cdb3-7ae2-facccdb3bb86",
base64val:"MENPSENJTFpZQzR3b1lvU1pQZTk=",
name:"john"
}
]
}
```

I know that the output would not be a valid json. it's intended for easily searchable logging purposes.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't edit json with regex, if possible ;) If you really have to, then you must find a simplification, i.e. there is no string that contains `:`. Then, you can try almost anything from the answers below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd do:

- find `"([^"]+)":`
- replace `$1:`

Comment: how does that work!? as far as I understand it selects everything up until the next `"`, it does not select all keys!? I would use something like `"[\w\d]*?":`

Comment: I've tested it via http://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html and works great (and looking at the regex now it makes so much sense). I'll verify it in my code later today and report here is there are any problems.

Comment: @xander: It selects every thing that is not a quote between 2 quotes, all followed by `:`. FYI `\w` includes `\d`

Answer (score 4):

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
For those who come looking for a javascript answer and who need compatibility with all valid JSON including keys containing escaped quotes (\"), colons (:), or whitespace (\s), here are 2 options.

```js
.replace(/("(\\[^]|[^\\"])*"(?!\s*:))|"((\\[^]|[^\\"])*)"(?=\s*:)/g, '$1$3')
```

OR

```js
function unquoteKeys(json) {
  return json.replace(/"(\\[^]|[^\\"])*"\s*:?/g, function (match) {
    if (/:$/.test(match)) return match.replace(/^"|"(?=\s*:$)/g, '');
    else return match;
  }
}
```

This type of function can be used to do almost anything with valid JSON.

```js
function modifyJson(json) {
  return json.replace(/"(\\[^]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?/g, function (match) {
    if (/^"/.test(match)) {
      if (/:$/.test(match)) {
        // match = Key with enclosing quotes & following colon (".*"\s*:)
      } else {
        // match = String (not key) with enclosing quotes (".*")
      }
    } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
      // match = Boolean value (true|false)
    } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
      // match = Null value (null)
    } else {
      // match = Number (-?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try it?

```
jsonStr.replaceAll("\"(\\w+)\":", "$1:"));
```

Regex remove quotes from keys

Answer (score 0):

You use find by regex:

```
\"(\w+)\"\:
```

and replace with

```
$1:
```

In any editor

and in java will be

```
String res = str.replaceAll("\\\"(\\w+)\\\"\\:","\\\\$1:")
```

Comment: you forgot the numbers in keys I guess :) replace `\w` with `[\w\d]`

Comment: No, not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no colon (`:`) in the jsonstr, except as key-value separator, you can experiment with lookaheads (`(?=...)` constructs) too:

```
jsonStr.replaceAll("\"(?=.*:)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
jsonStr.replace(/\"/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Above, @toto's method is quite concise and precise.
I can write it in detail this way:

```
text.replaceAll("\"([^\"]+)\":", "$1:")
```

Or you can try a more visual way like this:

```
String regex = "\"[a-z_]+\":";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String keyField = matcher.group(0);
    String keyFieldWithoutQuotes = keyField.replace("\"", "");
    text = text.replaceFirst(keyField, keyFieldWithoutQuotes);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

This way it will find key fields containing quotes one by one, then delete the quotes.